# In MVC Hidden field looses value set in javascript code after page is back , this issue is occuring in Internet Explorer only?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer, hidden-field

I have few hidden fields in my code, and setting the values for them in  java-script code , those are set perfectly , and  when I am posting those values to some other page through form ,that get received . But when I am going  page back to previous page (where I have set hidden field values ) through browser's back button, the Hidden fields values are getting lost that  I have set in java-script code .This behavior is occurring only in Internet Explorer while Chrome and Firefox shows the desired behavior.

Sample code to demonstrate behavior:

TestPage.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Testone", "Charts")) {
@Html.Hidden("test1")
    @Html.Hidden("test2")


    <input type="button" onclick="testfunction()" value="Click"/>
<button id="testbtn" > Button</button>
}



<script>


    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        alert('#####' + $('#test1').val() + '#######' + $('#test2').val());
    });

    function testfunction() {
        $('#test1').val(5);
        $('#test2').val(3);
    }


</script>
```

---

Here on clicking  'Click' button changes value of hidden fields , after that submitting this page to Testone controller will redirect it to Testone.cshtml . Now after that ,doing page back from browser's button to Test.cshtml will pop up values of hidden field , but if we again submit this page(Test.cshtml),it will shows null values for hidden fields. Please let me know if I am not clear on my question .Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a small demo that shows the issue, or a live site that breaks as a result of this problem? Also, which version(s) of Internet Explorer have you tested?

Comment: @Johnx Why do you feel Internet Explorer is not developer-friendly? I am an engineer on the IE team, a web-developer of 17+ years, and a regular user of Internet Explorer (I guess that goes without saying, heh).

Comment: @Johnx I do indeed follow community feedback. That's why when somebody says Internet Explorer is not friendly to developers, I ask why :) We focus a lot of effort on our Developer Tools (shipping features like Event Breakpoints/Tracepoints, before others), our Chakra engine (supporting much of ES6 before others), and Trident (supporting a great deal of CSS3 before others). Do you have specific issues I can help to address? Feel free to email me at josamp@microsoft.com.

Comment: @Johnx I look forward to talking with you more in the future. I'm going to delete my comments here in a couple of minutes as they are "too chatty" :)

Comment: @Johnx Can you please suggest possible workaround for this issue ?

Comment: @JonathanSampson Can you please suggest possible workaround for this issue ?

Comment: @JonathanSampson okz me too...

Comment: @JitendraTakzare im not a big fan on inline javascript, try bind the click event handler separately in the `document.ready`, try inspecting the values of hidden fields to make sure they are there...